# Does Google OAuth2.0 support grant_type=password?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

This is my command

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -d "client_id=111111111111%2D8pc07m34pj5eb5nid0u5n9fgs5vrndpm%2Eapps%2Egoogleusercontent%2Ecom&grant_type=password&username=123456%2E123%40gmail%2Ecom&password=123456&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Egoogleapis%2Ecom%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Egoogle%2Ecom"
```

but I keep getting:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

I am trying to write an app which can read calendar data of any gmail account specified in the command line:

```
./foo gmailID@gmail.com password
```

But I don't know how my foo can use gmailID and password to get a token w/o user interaction (i.e., open the url and click "Accept") so I can use the token to call Google Calendar APIs to read calendar data of that gmail account. I am new to this. Am I at least on the right track?

Comment: To help you start with your development, I think it's ideal to dig down to the standard documentations by google. [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) and [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/).

Comment: no you are not on the right track. See Ruben's answer.

Comment: Any answer on this in 2021 or else is it the same? I am looking if there is an API similar to what OKTA provides as in https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/29/what-is-the-oauth2-password-grant.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot send mail and password on `grant_type` and you cannot do requests on behalf of users without their permission, they need to give their consent.

In case you want to do requests on behalf of users (when they are not present in your application) you need to implement offline access. I suggest you to take a look on [this reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline).

Once users accept permissions to use your application, Google will generate a refreshToken that you need to store in your database. With that refreshToken you will be able to generate new access tokens and you will use these tokens to do your requests.

Comment: Yes I made that work. But why can iphone and android access the calendar data simply by letting user input the id and password? That is what I am trying to do

Comment: I've never tried that implementation, could you provide a link to documentation explaining it?